# What's the most used philosophy of keeping independent concepts separate in OOP?

Tags: oop, abstraction, decouple

Or according to your own experience,

what's your favorite trick ?

Comment: To steal Trumpi's answer from a similar(?) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845966/oop-good-class-design/845984#845984 And another answer by philippe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399656/are-there-any-rules-for-oop/399737#399737

Answer (score 2):

The #1 principle is encapsulation - at least the colleges have that part right.

Inheritance, polymorphism, cohesion, concision, coupling, dependency, etc... all these things really fall under that one umbrella.

> "Encapsulate by practice and expose by need."

The rest pretty much proceeds from there: Limit the number of places that a change forces you to revisit, ideally, every change to behavior would either be the beginning or the end of a chain-reaction (change the test then change the thing it tests) and every change to design would trigger absolutely no consequent changes.  This is a reality that is seldom achieved.

> "Find what varies and encapsulate it."

Don't use inheritance to give one class the behaviors of another; use delegation in its place.  Use inheritance to create *abstractions* behind which numerous *variations* live.  If you think you have a problem that requires you to degrade design, your problem is probably that, instead, your design needs to *improve*.

There's probably a good list of OOP code qualities somewhere with good descriptions, so I won't bother to retype it here.  Follow those principles, adapt your practices as your situation requires, and you should be pretty good to go.

Answer (score 0):

In my CSC 110 class I was taught Homer Simpson likes PIE (PIE being the big 3 concepts of object oriented programming).

P = polymorphism
I = inheritance
E = encapsulation

Comment: He likes DONUTS more, but DO Not Use This Saying.

Comment: This is why people end up being crushed when they come out of college and realize that a computer science degree has very little to do with software development.

So we're clear: that's a slam on your CSC 110 instructor, not you.

Comment: ha, i'm a graduate student here now.  I'll let her know you don't approve of her methods :)