# Creating Dependency Graphs in Python

Tags: python, dependency-management, call-flow

I have inherited a huge codebase that I need to make some small changes into. I was wondering if there are utilities that would parse python code and give dependencies between functions, as in if I make changes to a function I want to be sure that I dont break other functions, so if I could see in a graph like diagram it would make my life easier.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798389/python-tool-that-builds-a-dependency-diagram-for-methods-of-a-class

Answer (score 35, accepted):

- Usually "dependency" is defined for module / package import.
- What you are looking for is a visualizing call flow.

  - http://pycallgraph.slowchop.com/
- You can still not guarantee that you will not break functionality :)
- My experience and solution:

  Many a times, I found the call flow data overwhelming and the diagram too complex.
  So what i usually do is trace call flow partially for the function, I am interested in.

  This is done by utilizing the sys.settrace(...) function. After generating the call flows as textual data, I generate a call graph using graphviz.

  - http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html
  - [On call tracing](http://pyfunc.blogspot.com/2010/10/tracing-callflows-in-python.html)
  - For generating graphs, use graphviz solutions from [networkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/pygraphviz/).

[Edit: based on comments]

Then my piecemeal solution works better. Just insert the code and use the decorator on a function that you want to trace. You will see gaps where deferred comes into picture but that can be worked out. You will not get the complete picture directly.

I have been trying to do that and made a [few post](http://pyfunc.blogspot.com/search/label/Twisted) that works on that understanding.

Comment: +1 for last point about guarantees. I would be very impressed if it could follow much of the type of code that uses a lot of HOF and other dynamic features. I imagine that it would be useful mainly for evaluating the work of programmers that are either not smart enough to use such features or smart enough not to.

Comment: I am not looking for a silver bullet. What I am looking for is  more to give me a general idea.

Comment: @anijhaw : Then you got it. :) pycallgraph should do your job. I have also provided the solution which I use more frequently to learn what going on. This can be made difficult though. Try tracing calls in a twisted application.

Comment: it is a twisted application :(

Comment: your posts are great, I am trying your solution will keep you posted on how it turns out :)

Comment: The `pycallgraph` module has now been moved I think. Follow [this](https://pycallgraph.readthedocs.io/en/master/) link for documentation and it had become an unmaintained one.