# Constructing a dependency graph in python

Tags: python

I am trying to construct a python call graph as below,I have a change which has internal and external dependencies and these dependencies need to be 
recursivley into until each leaf gets a change which is closed...i have the logic to get the internal and external dependency ,I need some inputs  or a 
body how to construct a graph as below..

```
                 change
             /    \
            /      \
           /        \
internal dependency   external dependency
         / \                      /\   
        /   \                    /  \
   /     \                  /    \
  /       \                /      \
```

internal dep  external dep  internal dep external dep (repeat this until the dependency change is in closed state)

Comment: What is your best shot so far?

Comment: by "construct" do you mean print the graph you already have or what is your input?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4160800/297323

Comment: You may want to have a look at [snakefood](http://furius.ca/snakefood/) It does this specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be easier if you turn the expected output on its side. Then create a tree structure of what you want:

```
class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self, name, *children):
        self.name = name
        self.children = children

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(self.tree_lines())

    def tree_lines(self):
      yield self.name
      last = self.children[-1] if self.children else None
      for child in self.children:
          prefix = '`-' if child is last else '+-'
          for line in child.tree_lines():
          yield prefix + line
          prefix = '  ' if child is last else '| '


tree = Tree('Change',
    Tree('External',
        Tree('External A'),Tree('External B'),Tree('External C',Tree('Sub Ext C'))),
    Tree('Internal',
        Tree('Internal A'),Tree('Internal B',Tree('Sub Int B')),Tree('Internal C'))
    )   

print tree
```

Prints:

```
Change
+-External
| +-External A
| +-External B
| `-External C
|   `-Sub Ext C
`-Internal
  +-Internal A
  +-Internal B
  | `-Sub Int B
  `-Internal C
```