# Module dependency graph in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, dependency-management

How do I graph module dependencies in Python 3?  I found snakefood, but it seems to only work with Python 2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Dependency Graphs in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160746/creating-dependency-graphs-in-python)

Comment: @cyber: Unfortunately, I want the module dependencies rather than the call dependencies.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes… how is this not about programming — specifically "software tools commonly used by programmers"?

Comment: Did you find any dependency graph for Python3? I'm unable to build `snakefood` even with the fixes Terry suggested (missing bin folder)

Comment: @Motti No!  Please let me know if you find something.

Comment: Oh well, it's only been 5 years.

Comment: @motti See my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I built a tool based on [pydeps](https://pypi.org/project/pydeps/) [here](https://github.com/NeilGirdhar/graph_imports).

Comment: This would be more useful if there was any documentation whatsoever on how to use your package :)

Comment: @MartinCejp Thanks.  Feel free to contribute to `README.rst` :)  You just run it with your project directory as the sole argument and it spits out a diagram.

Answer (score 9):

I presume you are talking about this [snakefood](http://furius.ca/snakefood/), available on [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/snakefood/1.4), though not not updated there since 2009. Since it is an application intended to be run, rather than just a library of modules intended to be imported, you can execute it with Python 2.7 even if the target is a directory of Python 3 modules. It could be run from either 2.x or 3.x with subprocess. Its output files can be read equally well with any Python.

I cloned it with `hg clone --insecure <src> <dest>`.  My preliminary experiments indicate that very little change would be needed to run it with 3.x. I just needed the following in 2 of the 4 biggest files to get them to compile.

- `print x` => `print(x)`
- `except XError, e:` => `except XError as e:`

Comment: returns "invalid syntax" if run on a directory of python3 modules

Comment: @ErikAronesty It could well be that changes from 2014 to 2020 invalidated what I said then.  Better to use a more up-to-date program as suggested by Neil G's answer.

Answer (score 4):

python3 dependency graphs generator

https://github.com/Trim21/snakefood3

I had the same question 3 years ago, so I forked snakefood and fixed it for Python 3.

Comment: Thanks for writing this