# A module from which another module was imported

Tags: python, import, module

How can I determine from which module the module that I can find in sys.modules was imported from?

For example:
I have a module1.py and in it:
import module2
In module2.py:
import module3

Is it possible to somehow get information that module3 was imported from module2, and module2 from module1?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23962614/5320906) answer your question?