# Building python dependency graph on the fly

Tags: python

I want to determine the imports of each python module in a library for use in a custom configuration management framework.  I've seen tools like [snakefood](http://furius.ca/snakefood/), but I'd prefer to compute a dependency graph during normal program execution, instead of as a ~compilation step.

So far I've tried writing a custom [Finder and Loader](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#finders-and-loaders).  Both approaches work as expected the first time a module is imported, but don't trigger on subsequent imports thanks to the `sys.modules` cache.

I can override `__built__.__import__` for notifications every time a module is imported, but it seems like this approach is ill-advised since [PEP 302](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/).

Is there an import hook I can place in front of `sys.modules` cache lookups?  Or another way to quickly compute dependencies on the fly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Dependency Graphs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160746/creating-dependency-graphs-in-python)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the above. That question is looking for a call flow visualisation rather than a dependency graph and its accepted answer reflects that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible (if hacky) to reassign to `sys.modules`:

```
import sys
import inspect

old_sys_modules = sys.modules

class NewSysModules():
  def __getitem__(self, mod_name):
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    while frame.f_globals["__name__"].startswith("importlib"):
      frame = frame.f_back # go back until we're not in a importlib frame
    importer = frame.f_globals["__name__"]
    print(f"importing {mod_name} from {importer}")

    return old_sys_modules[mod_name]

  def __setitem__(self, mod_name, module):
    old_sys_modules[mod_name] = module

sys.modules = NewSysModules()
```

However, this might require some maintenance if the import system changes.

Comment: Thanks!  I tweaked this approach slightly (e.g. extended `collections.MutableMapping`) and it seems to work for Python 3.  Unfortunately we're on Python 2 until Apache Beam upgrades.  If I try to override sys.modules in Python 2, I get notified when `multiprocessing` is imported by `logging`, but I don't get other notifications I would expect.  I'll investigate further and report back.